# Selenium перестает работать браузер JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

на сервере Linux висит исполняемый файл jar, а именно Телеграм бот. Программа работает круглосуточно без остановок, парсит ссылки в интернете. Все работает несколько дней (2-3 дня) потом вылетает ошибка

```
Mar 17, 2020 6:19:26 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Marionette threw an error: <unprintable error>
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'autoru-1579587188088-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-88-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:438)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.WebSurfing.connect(WebSurfing.java:37)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.start(ParsinTop.java:41)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.run(ParsinTop.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient$Factory$1.lambda$createClient$1(OkHttpClient.java:152)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    ... 32 more
Mar 17, 2020 3:19:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFO: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stopThread(PumpStreamHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:452)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.WebSurfing.connect(WebSurfing.java:58)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.start(ParsinTop.java:41)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.run(ParsinTop.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

После чего идет перезагрузка браузера в моем случае Firefox на geckodriver. И после перезагрузки
вылетает новая ошибка

```
Mar 17, 2020 3:19:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFO: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stopThread(PumpStreamHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:452)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.WebSurfing.connect(WebSurfing.java:58)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.start(ParsinTop.java:41)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.run(ParsinTop.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Mar 17, 2020 3:19:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process java.lang.UNIXProcess@78019293

    ...
```

Но вместо того что-бы работать оно запускает браузер много раз под ряд после чего происходит конфликт. Новые открытые браузеры выдают ошибку и не закрываются а висят рабочими перенагружая сервер

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'autoru-1579587188088-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-88-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.WebSurfing.connect(WebSurfing.java:25)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.start(ParsinTop.java:41)
    at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.run(ParsinTop.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Сам класс где исполняется парсинг и запуск браузера

```
public class WebSurfing extends ArrayList<String>{

    public HashMap<String, String> connect(String url){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver"); // /usr/bin/geckodriver

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        try {
            url = url.replace("https://auto.ru/cars/", "https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/");
            driver.get(url);
            System.out.println("Connect to " + url);

            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button_blue']")).get(0).click();
            System.out.println("After accept");

            Thread.sleep(10000);
            try {
               Document document = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
               Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("Link CardDealerName-module__dealerName");

               hm.put("Результат", elements.get(0).attr("href"));
               System.out.println(hm.get("Результат"));
               hm.put("Конкурент", elements.get(0).text());
               System.out.println(hm.get("Конкурент"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                hm.put("Результат", " ");
                hm.put("Конкурент", " ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                driver.close();
            } catch (Exception e){}
            try {
                driver.quit();
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }

        return hm;
    }
}
```

Может я что-то делаю не так, в чем дело?

Comment: Необходимо полное описание проблемы, включая в чем дело.

Comment: @RomanC, не понятно в чем проблема. Оно работает несколько дней нормально. Потом в какой-то момент geckodriver выдает ошибку что в первом коде я прикрепил. После этого этот же geckodriver начинает запускать себя много раз не закрывая прошлые сессии, происходит конфликт по типу 
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method), такая ошибка у меня вылетала когда я запускал geckodriver не в свернутом режиме. В чем дело я пытаюсь понять уже вторую неделю, не понятно. Думал памяти на сервере не хватает, но про утечек памяти или недостатка предупреждений не было.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5447 может это.

Comment: url = url.replace("https://auto.ru/cars/", "https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/"); driver.get(url); не понятна эта строка!

Comment: А system.out.println вывод можно посмотреть.

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis с ссылками там все ок. Проблема немного не такая как у меня, но может действительно нужно обновить Selenium, попробую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сменил браузер на GoogleDriver, уже 4 день все работает как надо. Включаю браузер с параметрами

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

Бот летает. БД работает. Никаких ошибок нет. Правда скорость проверки ссылок ограничилась, думаю это из-за того что я перед каждым запросом открываю-закрываю браузер, если просто закрыть вкладку и открыть новую скорее всего будет работать быстрее. Так что проблема наверное была именно в браузере, или в стоке памяти, может FirefoxDriver сильно нагружал сервер в какой-то момент и все падало. Но в то же время FirefoxDriver проверял 3-4 ссылки с перезагрузкой самого себя, GoogleDriver в этом плане отстает, наверное из-за заданных параметров.